# Including code chunks in example/exercise blocks in pdf output

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

Bookdown extends R markdown by adding [environments for theorems, examples and exercises](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/markdown-extensions-by-bookdown.html#theorems) (and more). I'd like to place a code chunk inside an example environment:

````
```{example, label="ex1"}
Here is an example:

```{r eval=FALSE}
x <- 1+1
x+2
```

```
````

The desired output is the following:

---

**Example 1.** Here is an example:

```
x <- 1+1
x+2
```

---

The above code doesn't work, because the code chunk is already within a ``` environment.

I found the following workaround, which works fine when I knit the document to a html page:

````
```{example, label="ex1"}
Here is an example:

<pre><code>
x <- 1+1
x+2
</code></pre>

```
````

Unfortunately, this doesn't work when I knit the document to a pdf file - instead I just get a blank space. Is there a way to do this that works for both html and pdf output?

---

Update: another solution that doesn't work is the following (based on [this](https://yihui.org/en/2017/11/knitr-verbatim-code-chunk/)):

`````
  ```{example, label="ex1"}
  Here is an example:

  ````
  `r ''````x <- 1+1
  x+2
  ```
  ````
  ```
`````

In this case, the problem is that the line break between 1+1 and x+2 disappears.

Comment: I don't think there is a solution with the current version of **bookdown**, but I've been aware of this problem for a long time, and do plan to fix it in the future. Please feel free to file an issue to https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues Thanks!

Comment: @YihuiXie - Sure, I'll post an issue! I'll do some more experimenting with this first though - it appears that it fails (silently) in different ways in different parts of my document. I'll try to create a reprex showing different things that can go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is very simple and **independent** from your output format.
You can use this notation to include R chunks.

`````
````markdown
`r ''````{r}
plot(cars)
```
````
`````

The result:

[image]

Full credit to [Nathan Stephans](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360018181633-Including-verbatim-R-code-chunks-inside-R-Markdown)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think that that is what I'm looking for. I want to print the code inside the chunk without the ```{r} bit. Moreover, this solution doesn't work when used in the example environment. I've updated my question to clarify what I'm looking for.

Comment: I don´t get the point, so just remove the second and the second to last line.

Comment: If I do that inside an example environment, the output is:  `markdown x <- 1+1 x+2</div>\EndKnitrBlock{example}. Which isn't quite what I'm looking for. Please note that I specifically ask for verbatim text in the example environment.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why, but the following solution sort of works:

````
```{example, label="ex1"}
Here is an example:

```{r eval=FALSE}
x <- 1+1
x+2

```
````

It is my original proposal, with the second ``` removed.

The downside is that all text in the example after the ```{r eval=FALSE} part now becomes verbatim.